# Solve $a^2 \equiv b^2\ (mod\ N)$ by factoring number N?

Tags: number-theory, factoring, cryptography, prime-factorization

Find values $a$ and $b$ which satisfies $a^2 \equiv b^2\ (mod\ N)$ by factoring number $N = 52907$. Use given identities:

$$399^2 \equiv 480\ (mod\ N)\ \ \ 480 = 2^5 * 3 * 5$$
$$763^2 \equiv 192\ (mod\ N)\ \ \ 192= 2^6 * 3$$
$$773^2 \equiv 15552\ (mod\ N)\ \ \ 15552= 2^6 * 3^5$$
$$976^2 \equiv 250\ (mod\ N)\ \ \ 250= 2 *  5^3$$

What I did is calculate:

$$ 399^2 * 773^2 * 976^2 \equiv 480*1552*250\ (mod\ 52907) $$
$$ \equiv (2^5 * 3 * 5)*(2^6 * 3^5)*(2 * 5^3)\ (mod\ 52907) $$
$$ = 2^{12}* 3^6 * 5^4$$
$$ = (2^{6}* 3^3 * 5^2)^2 $$
$$ \equiv 43200^2\ (mod\ 52907) $$

Next:

$$399 * 773 * 976 \equiv 36829\ (mod\ 52907)$$

And: $gcd(52907, 43200-36829) = 277$. Thus $52907 = 277 * 191$.

But I am not sure if this is correct at all? Any help how to solve this kind of problem would be appreciate...

Comment: Um.... so what is your answer to a and b where $a^2 \equiv b^2 \mod 52907$?

Comment: @fleablood I think $a=277$ and $b=191$ but this does not satisfies congruence?

Comment: $277^2 = 277*(191+86) \equiv 86*277=23822 \mod 52907$.  $191^2 = 191*(277-86) \equiv -86*191=-16426 \equiv =36481 \mod 52907$ so no, that is not the answer.  Not sure why you thought is would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$52907 = 191*277$

$a^2 \equiv b^2 \mod 52907$ means $a^2 - b^2 = k*52907$

So $(a + b)(a-b) = k*191*277$

Several possible solutions.  If we ignore the trivial $a = n; b = \pm n$ for any integers $n$ (maybe by assuming $a$ and $b$ are positive and $a \ne b$) we can still find several where $(a+b)$ and $(a-b)$ are factors of $k*191*277*$.

The most apparent is $a+b = 277$ and $a - b = 191$ so $2b = 86; b=43;a=234$.  But there are infinitely many more.

(Example $a+b = 52907; a - b = anything;$ so $a= 907; b =52000$.  Or $a+b = 3*191; a-b=277;$ so $a$ and $b$ equal... whatever.)

=====

I'm honestly not sure what this exercise wants you to do or what the point is but I do notice that.

$192 = 2^6*3$ so $192*9^2 = 2^6*3^5 = 15552$

So $(763*9)^2 \equiv 192*9^2 = 15552 \equiv 773^2 \mod 52907$.

So $a = 763*9; b= 773$ then $a^2 \equiv b^2 \mod 52907$ answers your exercise.  However I must confess I see absolutely no point to this exercise and I have no idea what anyone can learn from it.

Comment: So this means my calculus is correct but incomplete. After finding factors of N, I should write $(a+b)(a-b) = k*factor_1*factor_2$ and and take $k=1$ and solve $a+b=factor_1, a-b=factor_2$?

Comment: Actually, I didn't understand your calculus at all.  Where you given those values?  Was part of the excercise to factor 52907?  Can take k to be any thing and take a+b and a-b to be any two q and N/q factors.  If factor1 is even and factor2 is odd you cant do this with k = 1.  But you can do others.

Comment: I did not understand problem exactly, but I have some other similar problem which uses this kind of calculus so I tried to apply it. I was given all values and I suppose to use them in solution. Googling a little bit I found Dixon’s factorization method and Congruence of squares should do something with this problem ...